# Check the box automatically or disable it using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I am trying to do either of the two things:

1) When all three boxes are checked (payments, picked up and returned), I want the fourth one(completed) to be checked automatically.

OR

2) I want the fourth box (completed) to be disabled until all the other boxes are checked.

I can't figure out either one using knockout js. Here is my code:

```
<div class="center">
    <h2> Grad Apparels </h2>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th></th>
                <th> ID Number </th>
                <th> Full Name </th>
                <th> Payments </th>
                <th> Picked Up </th>
                <th> Returned </th>
                <th> Completed </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: apparels">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: ($index() + 1)"> </td>
                <th data-bind="text: id"></th>
                <th data-bind="text: name"></th>
                <th> <input type="checkbox"> </th>  
                <th> <input type="checkbox"> </th> 
                <th> <input type="checkbox"> </th>
                <th> <input type="checkbox"> </th>
                <td> <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <p> ID: <input data-bind="value: id"> </p>

    <p> Full Name: <input data-bind="value: name"></p>
    <button data-bind="click: add">ADD</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function apparel(id, name){
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.name = ko.observable(name);
};

function viewModel(){ 
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable('');
    self.name = ko.observable('');
    self.apparels = ko.observableArray([
        new apparel(915486876, 'Shajia'),
        new apparel(915123456, 'John Doe'),
        new apparel(948037466, 'Katherine'),
        new apparel(958480376, 'Samuel'),
        new apparel(984803976, 'Jane Doe')
    ]);

this.add = function(){
    self.apparels.push(new apparel(self.id(), self.name()))
}

this.remove = function(){
    self.apparels.remove(this)
}

}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add three observables (`payments`, `pickedUp` and `returned`) and a computed (`allChecked`) to the `apparel` object:

```
    function apparel(id, name){
        var self = this;

        self.id = ko.observable(id);
        self.name = ko.observable(name);

        self.payments = ko.observable();
        self.pickedUp = ko.observable();
        self.returned = ko.observable();

        self.allChecked = ko.computed(function() {      
            return self.ch1() && self.ch2() && self.ch3();
        });
    };
```

And then use them in your table:

```
    <div class="center">
        <h2> Grad Apparels </h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr> 
                    <th></th>
                    <th> ID Number </th>
                    <th> Full Name </th>
                    <th> Payments </th>
                    <th> Picked Up </th>
                    <th> Returned </th>
                    <th> Completed </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: apparels">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: ($index() + 1)"> </td>
                    <th data-bind="text: id"></th>
                    <th data-bind="text: name"></th>

                    <th> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: payments"></th>  
                    <th> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: pickedUp"></th>  
                    <th> <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: returned"></th>  
                    <th> <input type="checkbox" disabled data-bind="checked: allChecked "> </th>
                    <td> <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.remove">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <p> ID: <input data-bind="value: id"> </p>

        <p> Full Name: <input data-bind="value: name"></p>
        <button data-bind="click: add">ADD</button>
    </div>
```